# MATLAB focus plot and apply correct tick labels

Tags: matlab, plot

I'd much rather be asking you about Bayesian analysis over this, but unfortunately, I am terrible with MATLAB plots (not due to a lack of effort though).

I have a plot attached. It contains 1739 days of data. I need to do the following three things:

1. Focus in on the plot so that the y axis limits are -1 and 1 (right now they are -4 and 14). I'm uninterested in any values beyond these limits.
2. Re-label the y axis from -1 to 1 in .10 increments.
3. Re-label the x axis so that it starts with 1, ends with 1739, and has enough points in between that it is still readable.

I've studied gca, datetick, ax=gca, etc. but I cannot accomplish any of these tasks without messing up the plot.

I am gracious for any assistance provided.
[image: Plot to modify]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the axis limits is very simple,

```
axis([1 1739 -1 1]) %// [xMin xMax yMin yMax]
```

And for the tick marks, do

```
set(gca,'XTick',-1:.1:1,'YTick',1:79:1739) %// 2*79 might be better than 79
```

after you create the plot. You can (should?) replace `gca` with the handle to the plot (do `h=plot(...` when you make the plot, then `set(h,'XTick',...`).

You should also go through [Matlab Plotting Basics](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/plotting-basics.html) which goes through all this kind of stuff in good detail.

Comment: Strange how you can't set the limits using `plot` directly. I guess they wanted to encapsulate that property within the axes directly instead of the plot.

Comment: You can also use `xlim` and `ylim` to change the limits on one axis at a time, which is often useful.

Comment: Thanks guys, everything worked but something strange happened. My data runs from 8/28/08 to 7/22/15. But MATLAB places 7/22/15 about 75% through the x-axis, not at the end. It then continues with 8/25/08 until it gets to the end of the plot. I've edited my original post to add a picture of what I'm describing to you.

Comment: That's a different question to your original one. Can you show the code you are using to make that 2nd plot?